# Hey when i save code in vs the line of code changes does anyone know how i fix it

Tags: visual-studio-code

[Hey when i save code in vs the line of code changes does anyone know how i fix it Demonstration of what the problem is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7S7cC.png)

Comment: Hi, I think you may have an auto formatter active. You should check in preferences / editor and your active plugins.

Answer (score 1):

Go to VS Code `File > Preferences > Settings` and Search For `format on save` if `Format on Save` is checked ,uncheck it.  Also see if `Format on type` is Checked or not

Comment: Its uncheck)://

Comment: Both options are unchecked?

Comment: yep both options are unchecked

Comment: Check this option `Insert Space After Type Assertion`

Comment: i see on the vs editor:format on save mode what i need to choose

Comment: all off on Insert Space After Type Assertion

Comment: `Insert Space After Opening And Before Closing Nonempty Parenthesis` ?

Comment: no you have maybe discord for Send you problems with pictures

Comment: Hit me up on `Sagar#1209`